# Howto fetch IDENTITY columns with ADO in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, ado, sap-ase, recordset

I´m having trouble to fetch **IDENTITY columns** with ADO in Delphi XE2.

**Question**
The ADO Fields property doesen´t return/contain any IDENTITY columns.
Is there a property or something in the connection that will enable to fetch IDENTITY columns or is this a known bug ?

**Scenario**
I have a stored procedure (in SYBASE ASE), that fetch 1 row with 4 columns.
One of the column is a IDENTITY column.

In this example: **ADOQuery.Fields.Count** will return 3 and not 4. The IDENTITY column is missing.

Ex:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
test: string;
Password: String;
UserName: string;
ServerName : string;
NoRec: integer;
MyValue: integer;

begin

Password:='xxxx';
UserName:='yyyy';
ServerName := 'zzzzz';

ADOConnection := TADOConnection.Create(Application);

with ADOConnection do
begin
  CommandTimeout := 0;
  IsolationLevel := ilSerializable;
  Attributes := [xaAbortRetaining];
  KeepConnection := True;
  LoginPrompt := False;

   ConnectionString := 'Provider=ASEOLEDB.1;Password=' + Password +
        ';Persist Security Info=True' + ';User ID=' +
        UserName + ';Data Source=' + ServerName; 
end;

if not Assigned(ADOQuery) then
begin
  ADOQuery := TADOQuery.Create(Application);
  with ADOQuery do
  begin
    CommandTimeout := 0;
    DisableControls;

    CacheSize := 500;
    Connection := ADOConnection;
    CursorType := ctOpenForwardOnly;
  end;
end;

ADOConnection.Open();
ADOQuery.SQL.Text:= 'sp_echo';
ADOQuery.Open;

NoRec:=ADOQuery.Fields.Count;  //This will return: 3, the IDENTITY col is missing

//Trying to fetch the column this way, will fail (the field doesen´t exist):
//MyValue:=ADOQUery.FieldByName('col_1').AsInteger
end;
```

**Here is script, table, stored procedure for this example**

```
create table tbl_echo
(
  col_1  numeric(10,0) identity,
  col_2  varchar(255),  
  col_3  int,
  col_4  int
)

insert into tbl_echo (col_2, col_3, col_4) select 'testing', 100, 200

create proc sp_echo
as
select top 1 * from tbl_echo
```

Comment: I am using a Stored Procedure that fetch 1 single row.

Comment: @Jens , it´s a SYBASE ASE Db.

Comment: Have you tried using TADOStoredProc?

Comment: Youre code is not valid, please edit it to be a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @Jens, it´s the same behavior if I use TADOStoredProc.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense now, why do you create an additional `TADODataSet`? Especially the assignment to `ADODataSet.RecordSet` seems unusual to me.

Comment: Please add the code where you attempt to access the column and it's not there.

Comment: @Jens, it´s the same behavior if I go:
    NoRec_1:=ADOQuery.Fields.Count;  //This will still be 3
    NoRec_2:=ADOQuery.Recordset.Fields.Count;  //This is 4

Comment: @MarcusAdams, that is not the problem here. I´m not getting the complete results when using a query with a IDENTITY column.

Comment: @carleson, but you know this without trying to access that column?

Comment: Even if you remove the `ADODataSet.RecordSet := ADOQuery.RecordSet;` assignment?

Comment: Yes @JensMühlenhoff, even if I remove ADODataSet and only use the ADOQuery.RecordSet. It will have the same effect. So the problem must be how Recordset are beeing populated or fetched in the first way (no matter if it´s a ADOQuery.RecordSet or ADODataSet.RecordSet)

Comment: @MarcusAdams how should i access a column that doesen´t exist ? Should I use DEV/NULL ?

Comment: Try `ADOQUery.FieldByName('col_1').AsFloat`

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you run the SQL code of the SP directly? `ADOQuery.SQL.Text := 'select top 1 * from tbl_echo'`

Comment: One other thing I can suggest is to turn on `Debug DCUs` and step through the ADO source code using the debugger.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff , using the SQL like: 'select top 1 * from tbl_echo', diden´t change anything. Same result. Obviously there is something fishy about how the ADOQUery.Fields work with IDENTITY columns (but Recordset.Fields seems to work)

Comment: Ok, I suggest you simplify your code examples in the question then.

Comment: The problem may very well be the ADO driver or some setting of the ADO driver. Maybe it's the data type, you could try `INT IDENTITY` instead of `NUMERIC(10, 0) IDENTITY` just to rule out the base data type.

Comment: Your code doesn't create a new query component if it already exists. Do you maybe have one with persistent fields?

Comment: No, @MarcusAdams thats not any problem here. You could just add that code into e new project, without any other code and this will happend every time. But if I remove IDENTIDY from the "Col_1" field in my table, the FIELDS property will return correct number of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I´ve tried to use some other providers with the same result.

One simple solution for this problem is just to cast the IDENTITY column to an integer in my procedure/query. By doing that it works like expected.

```
create proc sp_echo
as
select top 1  cast(col_1 as int) as col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4 from tbl_echo
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two different ways to get what you want:

1. You declare an output parameter in your SP and, after inserting, assign `@@IDENTITY` to this parameter. Execute such a SP by using a `TADOStoredProc` component, not a `TADOQuery` component. After the SP finnishes, when the control comes back to your Delphi code you just read the value of such a parameter.
2. You simply select `@@IDENTITY`, what will give you a result set with a single row with a single column containing the generated value. In this case you can use a `TADOQuery`, but in your Delphi code you use `Open` (not `ExecSQL`) to retrieve such a resultset and just read the value from the only field is has.

Comment: @AlexSH, thanks for your answer. But I don´t think this is a solution for my situation. I have a huge codebase and several 1000 procedures, so it´s not an option to review and rewrite all of these. Our current (and very old sybase driver) manage to support IDENTITY fields in all our query´s and I find it strange that ADO would not support this. I will do some experiment with some other "providers" and see if they have the same behavior as this ASEOLEDB.1

Comment: @carleson: I hope you will have luck with that, but personally, I doubt it. My experience with OLE-DB tells me that there is no an `IDENTITY` type in parameters or columns data types. In fact, that seems to be impossible since `IDENTITY` is not like `AutoInc` in datasets, it's a session generated value that exists in the data server until the next row insertion with  `IDENTITY`. There is no way to transfer such a value without the participation of the stored procedure code.